# Unable to get data from Json Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am fetching some data from external Webservice and parsing it to json using [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq](http://json.codeplex.com/)

like this

```
 JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
 JArray sizes = (JArray) o["data"];
```

Now the `Sizes` looks like this

```
{
    [
        {
            "post_id": "13334556777742_6456",
            "message": "messagecomes her",
            "attachment": {
                "media": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://onurl.html",
                        "alt": "",
                        "type": "link",
                        "src": "http://myurl.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "come to my name",
                "href": "http://mydeeplink.html",

                "description": "",
                "properties": [],
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get `"src": "http://myurl.jpg"`element from this Json array.
I have tried:

```
foreach (JObject obj in sizes)
{
    JArray media = (JArray)obj["attachment"];
    foreach (JObject obj1 in media)
    {
        var src = obj1["src"];
    }
}
```

But it's throwing an error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.
```

at this line

```
JArray media = (JArray)obj["attachment"];
```

Can any one give me a hand on this?

Comment: obj is  **JObject**  and  media is  **JArray** . You cannot cast JObject to JArray

Comment: @MicrosoftDN can you suggest an alternative as answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try fix line

```
JArray media = (JArray)(obj["attachment"]);
```

to

```
JArray media = (JArray)(obj["attachment"]["media"]);
```

Comment: it is still throwing error - Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handled a scenario that sounds just like yours:

```
public static IList<Entity> DeserializeJson(JToken inputObject)
    {
        IList<Entity> deserializedObject = new List<Entity>();

        foreach (JToken iListValue in (JArray)inputObject["root"])
        {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            entity.DeserializeJson(iListValue);
            deserializedObject.Add(entity);
        }

        return deserializedObject;
    }

 public virtual void DeserializeJson(JToken inputObject)
    {
        if (inputObject == null || inputObject.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            return;
        }

        inputObject = inputObject["entity"];

        JToken assertions = inputObject["assertions"];

        if (assertionsValue != null && assertionsValue.Type != JTokenType.Null)
        {
            Assertions assertions = new Assertions();
            assertions.DeserializeJson(assertionsValue);
            this.Assertions = assertions;
        }

// Continue Parsing
}
```